# Need to sort items alphabetic in a dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu, viewbag

here is the "problem"
I need to order the items of a dropdownlist alphabetically ...

this is my view

```
<label for="Contenido">Reparticion</label>  
<div class="control">
    <%: Html.DropDownList ("reparticionId", (SelectList)ViewBag.ReparticionIdSelectList)%>            
</div>
<div class="spacer"></div>
<label>Depósito</label>  
<div class="control">
    <%: Html.DropDownList("deposito", (SelectList)ViewBag.DepositoIdSelectList)%>            
</div>
<div class="spacer"></div>
```

here is my viewbag in the controller...

```
private void CargarControlesReparticion() {
    //Crear listado de Reparticion
    this.ViewBag.ReparticionListado = new SelectList(ReparticionNegocio.Listado(), "ReparticionId", "Descripcion");
}

private void CargarControlesDeposito() {
    //Crear Listado Deposito
    this.ViewBag.DepositoListado = new SelectList(DepositoNegocio.Listado(), "DepositoId", "Nombre");
 }
```

any ideas??? thanks...

Answer (score 0):

use LINQ to sort the items in your list

```
var sortedList = (from entry in ReparticionNegocio.Listado() orderby entry.Value ascending select entry);
this.ViewBag.ReparticionListado = new SelectList(sortedList, "ReparticionId", "Descripcion");
```

Comment: Hi Eranga... It didn't work... I wrote the line and replaced value for "Descriotion"... and the list still show up in the wrong order...
any other ideas??? thank you...

Comment: what type of objects are return by your `Listado()` method?

Comment: strings from a database table.